# Imagick with laravel not throwing error

Tags: php, apache, imagemagick, imagick, laragon

I am using imagick with **laragon** which i think i have configured properly since its showing in the phpinfo. I am trying to simply convert an image into pdf and i have doubled check the image exists. When i try to get the image via imagick it takes a lot of time and finally shows error

**FAILED TO LOAD RESPONSE**

I cant seem to figure out what is the cause of this. This the method i am using

```
      $uploadImg = new \Imagick("http://finlinkweb.qa/backend/storage/app/data/uploads/user/17/reference_material/de68b985239e26ff2cb32266ac9f087d.png");
        $uploadImg->setImageFormat('pdf');
        $uploadImg->writeImage(config('constants.back_end.data_without_app') . "file.pdf");
```

These are my specs :

- PHP Version 7.1.7
- Architecture x64
- Loaded Configuration - File C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.1.7-Win32-VC14-x64\php.ini
- Thread Safety    enabled
- Imagic Version : ImageMagick 7.0.7-19 Q16 x64 2018-01-01

Comment: What was the error message?  If I try to go to your link to the input png file, my browser says it cannot find it. Is that the correct link?

Comment: Its my local machine..